# Do jeweler and gemspec in Gemfile work together?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I've got a problem when using `gemspec` in my Gemfile and using jeweler:

```
sudo gem install
pkg/revertible_paper_trail-0.3.0.gem
Fetching: revertible_paper_trail-0.3.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing pkg/revertible_paper_trail-0.3.0.gem:
    revertible_paper_trail requires revertible_paper_trail (>= 0)
```

`rake gemspec:debug` shows that this got added:

```
if Gem::Version.new(Gem::VERSION) >= Gem::Version.new('1.2.0') then
  s.add_runtime_dependency(%q<revertible_paper_trail>, [">= 0"])
```

When dropping `gemspec` from the Gemfile, the runtime dependency vanishes and installing the gem works.

Now, what's best practice when using jeweler and bundler?

FYI: The code for the gem is at https://github.com/CyTeam/revertible_paper_trail

Answer (score 3):

`gem install` has nothing to do with bundler or your Gemfile, so this question is very confusing. (BTW, your code link goes to a 404 page.)

Comment: Well, I'm confused too, that's the problem;-) What I see is that jeweler does add a strange runtime dependency on the gem itself with version specification >= 0 to the gemspec it generates. But only if the `gemspec` declaration is in the Gemfile.
This self-referencing dependency seems then to hinder `gem install` to do a successful install.
BTW: Link fixed (thx @iceydee!)

Answer (score 2):

Stop using `jeweler` and just [maintain your own `.gemspec`](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/04/02/using-gemspecs-as-intended/).

Comment: Well, I don't mind creating .gemspec myself, but really like the tagging/releasing part of jeweler. After reading Yehuda's post for another time (did know it), I've seen the link to Sven Fuchs' [gem-release]https://github.com/svenfuchs/gem-release which could fill this part. Probably giving it a try. So: thank you for making me rethink this again, but the tough and terse language almost made me vote your comment down:-)